# TypeError: ufunc 'isnan' not supported for the input types

Tags: python-3.x, seaborn, categorical-data

I am using a heatmap for categorical variables. I have made sure that I don't have any NaN values in my dataframe, but I am facing this issue constantly. What can the potential problem be?

```
ufunc 'isnan' not supported for the input types, and the inputs could not be  
    safely coerced to any supported types according to the casting rule ''safe''
```

Comment: Noone can have only the slightest clue about what you're doing to get this error. See [ask] and [mcve].